# Create a text file with the logged in user as its filename

Tags: vbscript, login-script, createfile

I have this script that is creating and updating a text file called Machine.txt and populates it with a list of lines which have this format (username, time and date when the script ran).

I’m running this at logon.

What I want to do is to create a new text file for each user who logs in.

Example, if user is called fred I want the script to create fred.txt.

Any ideas?

**Script been used is shown below i have replaced file location and name with "filepath and name"
thnak you for any help you can provide.**

```
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set WSHNetwork = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Network")
Set WSHSysEnv = WSHShell.Environment ("PROCESS")

On Error Resume Next 

' Check what OS is being used

Dim valOS

    valOS = WSHShell.RegRead ("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows     NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName")


Dim valPath, valLocation

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
valMachine = objEnv("COMPUTERNAME")
valDate = date
valTime = time

' This section of the script look for a hidden file on a users private share. This   file is used to store a list of 
' machines that a client has logged onto and the date and time that they logged on


Set oFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If oFSO.FileExists ("filepath and name") Then ' If this file exists open the file for  appending

    Set oAppend = oFSO.OpenTextFile ("filepath and name",8) ' Open the text file for  appending
    oAppend.Writeline valMachine & "," & valDate & "," & valTime ' Write the machine name, date and time the the user logged onto the client
    oAppend.close ' Close the text file connection
    valPath = ""
    valDate = ""
    valTime = ""
Else
    Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile ("filepath and name") ' Create the file
    Set objFile = oFSO.GetFile ("filepath and name") ' Attach to the file
    objFile.Attributes = 2 ' Change the file attribute to hidden
    oStream.Writeline valMachine & "," & valDate & "," & valTime ' Write the machine      name, date and time the the user logged onto the client
    oStream.close ' Close the text file connection
    valPath = "" ' Clear the valPath variable
valDate = "" ' Clear the valDate variable
valTime = "" ' Clear the valTime variable

End If 

wscript.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim objNetwork
Dim userName

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = objNetwork.UserName
```

Assign userName as your file name with a .txt extension

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i dont normaly work with Scrips so could you provide abit more information. to created file i have Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile ("filepath/filename.txt")

Comment: What more are you looking for?  If you post your script, we can tell you what you need to do (which probably explains the downvotes).  The script snippet in my answer will get you the name of the person logged in.  You just need to find in your script where it creates the text file, and replace the file name with userName + ".txt"

Comment: Add the 4 lines I posted in the answer at the top under Dim valOS.  Then you can do something like: Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile ("C:\path\" + userName = ".txt")  That will create a text file with the name of the current logged in user, in a folder called c:\path (which you can obviously change)

Comment: I have added the 4 line under Dim valOS, i then change scrip so it would show any errors. i then added in for testing  Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile ("c:\temp\" + userName = ".txt")now when the scrip run it gives no error but does not created a text file. thank you for all your help so far Andrew.